# Matlab linear equations with binary solutions

Tags: matlab, binary, system, linear-equation

I have a linear equation (binary) system:

```
x+1=0;
x+1=y;
x=1;
```

It has binary solutions x=1,y=0; But I don't know how to solve this system in matlab, could anybody help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Try looking at `intlinprog`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html

Comment: Your first equation would indicate _x=-1_. Your third equation says _x=1_. That is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @RPM not necessarily. If this is in the Galois Field of 2 (GF-2) domain, this is binary addition modulo 2 so 1+1=0...but that hasn't been made clear by the OP.